# CardLayout and recycle view can't get my view elements in viewholder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-cardview

I am trying to build a simple recycle view with a adapter, im following [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465) tutorial to archieve that.

When i am working on my adapter setting everything inside i get a error saying that i need to transform all my elements(TextViews and those) into static fields, the author doesn't need that and i don't know why.

This is my code:

```
public class SimiliarPlantsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimiliarPlantsAdapter.PlantViewHolder>{

ArrayList<Plant> plants = new ArrayList<Plant>();

public static class PlantViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView cv;
    TextView plantName;
    TextView plantCheck;
    ImageView plantPhoto;

    PlantViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        plantName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.plantName);
        plantCheck = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.plantCheck);
        plantPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.plantPhoto);
    }

}

@Override
public PlantViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.similiar_photo_row, viewGroup, false);
    PlantViewHolder pvh = new PlantViewHolder(v);
    return pvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PlantViewHolder holder, int position) {
    PlantViewHolder.plantName.setText(plants.get(position).getSpecie());
    PlantViewHolder.plantCheck.setText("Are you sure this is the plant?");
    PlantViewHolder.personPhoto.setImageResource(plants.get(position).photoId);
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return plants.size();
}

public SimiliarPlantsAdapter(ArrayList<Plant> plants) {
    this.plants = plants;
}
```

**the problem is here:**

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PlantViewHolder holder, int position) {
        PlantViewHolder.plantName.setText(plants.get(position).getSpecie());
        PlantViewHolder.plantCheck.setText("Are you sure this is the plant?");
        PlantViewHolder.personPhoto.setImageResource(plants.get(position).photoId);
    }
```

my **plantName and plantCheck** doesn't work, i need to transform the initialized values into static fields, why is that happening, any tip?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change **onBindViewHolder** method i think the way you accessing properties in 
**PlantViewHolder** class is wrong.do it like this

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PlantViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.plantName.setText(plants.get(position).getSpecie());
    holder.plantCheck.setText("Are you sure this is the plant?");
}
```

you don't have to use `static` **holder object** is already passed inside the method try to access it's variable with that passed referenc
e

Comment: my answer to this is that im stupid that it even hurts, thank you for the catch :D

Answer (score 0):

Use `PlantViewHolder's` object `holder` to set `views` property.

**Update `onBindViewHolder` as below:**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PlantViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.plantName.setText(plants.get(position).getSpecie());
    holder.plantCheck.setText("Are you sure this is the plant?");
    holder.personPhoto.setImageResource(plants.get(position).photoId);
}
```

Comment: Ty for the help but your answer is the same as above